# Why the value of the parameter changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def getGraphWave(G, d, maxk, p):
    data = dict()
    output_wavelets = {2:33,5:77,...}
    print(len(output_wavelets)) 
    k = [10,20]  
    for i in k:
        S = graphwave(i, output_wavelets)
        # size = avgSize(G, S, p, 200)
        size = IC(d, S, p)
        data[i] = size + i
    return data
```

The `output_wavelets` is a dict and the length of it is 2000.
However, when running the following code:

```
def graphwave(k, output_wavelets):
    S = []
    print(len(output_wavelets))
    for i in range(k):
        Seed = max(output_wavelets, key=output_wavelets.get)
        S.append(Seed)
        output_wavelets.pop(Seed)
    return S
```

In the `getGraphWave(G,D,maxk,p)`, `graphWave(k,output_wavelets)` runs two times in the circulation. However, Why in the `graphWave()`, the result of `print(len(output_wavelets))` is 2000 and 1991?
I thought `output_wavelets` is not changed before `output_wavelets`. And how to let `output_wavelets` always be the original?

Comment: example input and example output please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700609/173314 gives a very long explanation of what's happening here. The short version is that `graphwave()` is passed the `output_wavelets` list itself, not a copy of it, so when you call `output_wavelets.pop(Seed)` you are modifying the list.

Comment: I use `ow = deepcopy(output_wavelets)  S = graphwave(i, ow)` to solve this problem. But I don`t know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `graphwave(i, output_wavelets)` this passes **a reference to** `output_wavelets` into the function, not a copy of `output_wavelets`.  This means that when the function modifies the `output_wavelets` dictionary it is modifying the original dictionary.

The `output_wavelets.pop(Seed)` line removes items from the dictionary, so is modifying the `output_wavelets` dictionary that you passed in.  That is why it is getting smaller!

There are various ways which you could fix this.  The simplest (but probably not the most efficient) would be to use the [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) function to make a copy of your dictionary at the start of the `graphwave` function, and edit the copy rather than the original.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how value pass in python. Actually it depend on param which you passing to function. 
like if you pass list, dict or any mutable object.. it can modify within the function.
but if you pass tuple, string or any immutable object.. it will not change.

In your case you can copy existing dict and then modify it. like

`temp_output_wavelets = copy.deepcopy(output_wavelets)`